# plotting NA on a ggplot scatter plot with weighted points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the following data:

```
  UKPRN    Subject    Total.number easting northing
1 10033225 Computing  NA           516857   209364
2 10035012 Computing  NA           337767   402199
3 10000571 Computing  NA           369406   163887
4 10034119 Computing  NA           567497   193951
5 10007140 Computing  7            407643   287149
6 10007140 Computing  5            407643   287149
```

I want to keep the NA data on the map, placing it as a cross, whilst plotting the numbered values as circles with a size. I use:

```
ggplot(map_data, aes(easting, northing, size = Total.number)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 2/3)
```

But the NA values aren't mapped.  Any idea how I do this?

```
Warning message:
Removed 66 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another `geom_point` layer only including the NA values:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=map_data, aes(easting, northing, size = Total.number), alpha = 2/3) +
  geom_point(data=map_data[is.na(map_data$Total.number),], aes(easting, northing),  shape=3)
```

[image]

Comment: thank's I need to get my head around combining multiple plots

Comment: If you set `aes(x = easting, y = northing)` in the original `ggplot()` call, because the column names are the same in both data frames you wouldn't have to re-specify those mappings in each layer. (Though you'd want to keep `aes(size = Total.number)` in the first point layer only.)